# Cannot create a resource following AWS IAM policy enforcement using CloudFormation

Tags: aws-cloudformation, amazon-iam, aws-iam-policy

The following IAM enforcement policy is attached with the AWS IAM role that I assume as an SSO user. When I use AWS CLI, I can create the Security group. But when I try to create this security group using CloudFormation with the same tag name/value and running using the same AWS Profile, I get error `You are not authorized to perform this operation`.

IAM enforcement policy attached to the role that I assume:

```
{
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Action": "ec2:CreateSecurityGroup",
    "Resource": "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:security-group/*",
    "Condition": {
        "StringLike": {
            "aws:RequestTag/Name": "*UserDefined*"
        }
    }
}
```

AWS CLI script. Security group is created successfully:

```
VPC_ID='vpc-12345678901234567'
AWS_PROFILE='my-aws-profile'
AWS_REGION='eu-west-1'

aws ec2 create-security-group \
    --profile ${AWS_PROFILE} \
    --region  ${AWS_REGION} \
    --description "For Testing" \
    --group-name "my-test-security-group" \
    --vpc-id ${VPC_ID} \
    --tag-specifications 'ResourceType=security-group,Tags=[{Key=Name,Value=UserDefined-my-test-sg}]'
```

CloudFormation Template to create the same security group with the same AWS Profile, but fails:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'

Parameters:
  VPC:
    Type: AWS::EC2::VPC::Id
    Default: vpc-12345678901234567

Resources:
  MySecurityGroup:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
      GroupName: my-test-security-group
      GroupDescription: For Testing
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
      Tags:
      - Key: Name
        Value: UserDefined-my-test-sg
```

Error I get when trying to deploy the CloudFormation stack using the above template:
`You are not authorized to perform this operation. User: arn:aws:sts:::assumed-role/AWSRstrictedSSO_Ops_7f991be0d78c1285/user@company.com is not authorized to perform: ec2:CreateSecurityGroup on resource: arn:aws:ec2:eu-west-1:12345678012:security-group/* because no identity-based policy allows the ec2:CreateSecurityGroup action.`

What am I missing here when using CloudFormation?

Answer (score 0):

It might be related to the underlying process of Cloudformation.

The CLI invoked operation is a single call to EC2 service with tags included in the request. In this case, condition that verifies aws:RequestTag/Name returns true and you are allowed to create SG.

With Cloudformation it's not so obvious and it could be that resource creation operation is separate from resource tagging operation.

I just checked and there are 3 events for SG in CloudTrail

1. Create SG With the following parameters

```
    "requestParameters": {
            "groupName": "my-test-security-group",
            "groupDescription": "For Testing",
            "vpcId": "vpc-824463e4"
        },
```

2. Create CloudFormation related Tags with parameters

```
    "requestParameters": {
            "resourcesSet": {
                "items": [
                    {
                        "resourceId": "sg-0dd3638be585ad490"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "tagSet": {
                "items": [
                    {
                        "key": "aws:cloudformation:stack-name",
                        "value": "sgTestStack"
                    },
                    {
                        "key": "aws:cloudformation:stack-id",
                        "value": "arn:aws:cloudformation:eu-west-1:829878228038:stack/sgTestStack/e4655cd0-8329-11ee-977b-0667e136f8a7"
                    },
                    {
                        "key": "aws:cloudformation:logical-id",
                        "value": "MySecurityGroup"
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
```

3. Create Tags defined for the resource in CF

```
    "requestParameters": {
            "resourcesSet": {
                "items": [
                    {
                        "resourceId": "sg-0dd3638be585ad490"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "tagSet": {
                "items": [
                    {
                        "key": "Name",
                        "value": "UserDefined-my-test-sg"
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
```